# How did Superman learn to control his super hearing and super sight?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, powers

In the comics, how did Superman learn to control his super hearing and super sight? Did they work perfectly when they first started, or did he have to learn how to handle them, perhaps being overwhelmed by his senses until he learns to focus? Did someone help with the process, or did he learn it by himself?

Answers with specific references to specific graphic novels or issues much appreciated, so that I can find the relevant stories myself, but answers without that are perfectly acceptable as I am definitely NOT asking for a list or recommendations.

Comment: By *super-sight*, are you referring to his ability of seeing far-away objects clearly, or his x-ray vision?

Comment: Either and both

Comment: There are [entire comic serials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superboy) devoted to young Superman learning to use his powers;

Comment: @Valorum would you say that there is one that is nowadays considered definitive, much as Batman Year 1 is considered definitive, such that an answer might be found there? Still I take your point, I can see that the answers are many, and it might be interesting to know the best ones. Sadly I am limited in what I can ask and how I can ask it for fear of breaking topic rules

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke - The problem with asking Superman questions is that it's like trying to swallow the ocean unless you narrow it down. He's been in 10 feature films, a dozen TV series, dozens of animated episodes, dozens of comic serials (including his own imprint, plus a dozen spinoffs) and literally *tens of thousands* of individual comics.

Comment: @Valorum I completely agree. However, when I tried to ask this question in a form that recognised that problem and provided guidance as to what exactly I was looking for, it was downvoted and put on hold as asking for a list. So I am wary of hitting that problem again. I can tell you that I am specifically seeking something that could be used as an example for a child struggling with their experiencing the noisiness and brightness of the world, something that could help them see their unusual perception of it as something good rather than something bad, and how to deal with it.

Comment: @JamesCarlyle-Clarke  -It sounds like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRfpZD2ggx0) is what you're after. I can't think of a comparable scene from the comics

Comment: Yes, I remember that, though it's a) film, not a comic, and b) a bit scary for what I had in mind. I do recall seeing such a scene in the comics, somewhere. I think I remember (young) Superman doubled over from the pain of all the overwhelming sounds, and seeing X-ray vision of everything and not being able to see what everything was. Then he focussed somehow, and managed to listen to only one sound, and somehow got his vision under control too. However as you say, there are so many versions that I hesitated to include that in my question as it may be a composite of several versions.

Comment: I'm wondering if Superman For All Seasons (apparently the catalyst for Smallville), Superman: Birthright (the early 2000s canon origin story) or Superman Secret Origin (replacement for Birthright) might be what I'm remembering... I'll look for them at the library/bookstore, can anyone comment?